# I keep getting .success as false

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have to read an excel file and check if its name follows a certain pattern.

The pattern is CDFSDDRCxxxCurryymmdd, where xxx is a number, Curr is either EUR or GBP and yymmdd is a date.

This is my file's name, CDFSDDRC603EUR120124.xls. Can also be .xlsx.

And this is my code.

```
Match nameIsValid = Regex.Match(activeWorkbook.Name,
@"CDFSDDRC(?<xxx>[0-9]+)(?<xxx>[A-Z]+)(?<yymmdd>[0-9][0-9][0|1][0-9][0-3][0-9])\.xls?");
```

I keep getting nameIsValid.success as false.
I think my Regex expression is ok, but then again.
Any ideas?
Rui Martins

Comment: At the end you have "xls?" meaning that the s is optional. I think you want "xlsx?" meaning the x is optional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern for the date matching is somewhat messed up. It doesn't really match dates but just a weir combination of numbers. Also, you can't use `|` inside character classes. Think closely about how dates are constructed.

Furthermore, you have a duplicate matching group called `xxx`. This will surely mess up C#'s behaviour when accessing one of them.

Try this one

```
/CDFSDDRC(?<xxx>\d+)(?<curr>[A-Z]+)(?<yymmdd>\d{2}(?:0[1-9]|1[12])(?:(?:0|1|2)[1-9]|3[0-2]))\.xlsx?/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CDFSDDRC(?<xxx>\d+)(?<curr>EUR|GBP)(?<yymmdd>\d{2}[0-1]\d[0-3]\d)\.xlsx?
```

The following works for me for both xls and xslx.

Comment: This will allow `00` months and `00` days - I didn't know that such things exist ;)